# Can't resume AudioTrack after pause

Tags: java, android

I am currently using AudioTrack in stream mode to play some prerecorded tracks. Play and stop mechanics work properly.However, when i hit pause and try to resume afterwards the buffer only reads -1, indicating that the EOF was reached.

I tried to mark and reset the Inputstream, like it's suggested in some posts but it didn't help.

```
public void pauseTrack() {
  currentAudioTrack.pause();
  isPaused = true;
}

public void resumeTrack() {
  isPaused = false;
}

@Override public void run() {
  try {
    while (offset < audioFile.length()) {
      if (isPaused)
        continue;
      currentAudioTrack.play();
      int numberOfBytesRead = fileInputStream.read(audioData);
      if (numberOfBytesRead != -1) {
        currentAudioTrack.write(audioData, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
        offset+=numberOfBytesRead;
      }
      else {
        return;
      }
    }
    Log.v("status", "finished reading");
  } catch (IOException io) {
    Log.v("Exception", "IOException found: " + io.getLocalizedMessage());
  } catch (IllegalStateException ie) {
    Log.v("Exception","IllegalStateException:" + ie.getLocalizedMessage());
  }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried the skip method of InputStream? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip%28long%29
With this you could skip to the position of `numberOfBytesRead`

Comment: Despite the skip method forwards the InputStream correctly, audiotrack doesn't play any sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give some closure to the post, i ended up changing to the AudioTrack static mode. The change wasn't because of the pause situation, however it end up solving it. Since the buffer writing is done all in one take, it doesn't present the challenges of the stream mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void pauseTrack()
{
  currentAudioTrack.pause();
  isPaused = true;
}

public void resumeTrack() 
{
  isPaused = false;
}

@Override public void run() 
{
  try {
        while (offset < audioFile.length()) 
        {
          if(isPaused != true)
          {
              currentAudioTrack.play();
              int numberOfBytesRead = fileInputStream.read(audioData);
              if (numberOfBytesRead != -1) {
                currentAudioTrack.write(audioData, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
                offset+=numberOfBytesRead;
              }
              else {
                return;
              }
          }

        }
    Log.v("status", "finished reading");
  } catch (IOException io) {
    Log.v("Exception", "IOException found: " + io.getLocalizedMessage());
  } catch (IllegalStateException ie) {
    Log.v("Exception","IllegalStateException:" + ie.getLocalizedMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: The outcome is the same. My approach was to stop the writing when the track is paused and resume it when the track is resumed. However, the fileInputStream reads -1 as if the file as reached its end.

Answer (score 0):

I used the skip() method, as below, to skip the offset which is recorded when pause is triggered. Works fine sofar.

```
public void play() {
try {

     dis.skip(offset);  //skip "offset * bufferSize" in the **dis** data input stream 

     while (((i = dis.read(music_chunk, 0 , 0)) > -1) && !isPaused) {
           i = dis.read(music_chunk, 0, bufferSize);
           track.write(music_chunk, 0, i);   // track is the AudioTrack
           position += bufferSize;
     }
     track.stop();
}

public void pause() {   
      track.pause();
      offset      = position ;
      isPaused    = true;   
}
```

Please adjust the above code to your needs before running.

Thanks